# sort vector of object don't work

Tags: c++

it's first question in this website, i want to order by points acquired, the team ranking, there's any error but the shorting don't work. 
I want your help to overcome this problem

Team.h

```
class Team
{
private:
    std::string t_name;
    int t_rank;

public:
    int t_points;
    Team(std::string name);
    ~Team();
    void win();
    void show(std::ostream &Flux)const;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &Flux, Team const &B);
bool operator<(Team const& A,Team const& B);
```

Team.cpp

```
Team::Team(string name): t_name(name), t_points(0) {}

void Team::win()
{
    t_points+=3;
}

void Team::show(std::ostream &Flux)const
{
    Flux << t_name;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &Flux, Team const &B)
{
    B.show(Flux);
    return Flux;
}

bool operator<(Team const& A,Team const& B){
    return A.t_points < B.t_points;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    vector <Team*> Schedule;

    Schedule.push_back(new Team("Celtics")); //0
    Schedule.push_back(new Team("Nets"));//1
    Schedule.push_back(new Team("Bulls"));//2

    Schedule[1]->win();
    Schedule[1]->win();
    Schedule[2]->win();

    std::sort(Schedule.begin(), Schedule.end());
    for(int i(0); i<Schedule.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i << " - " << *Schedule[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have edit my files to add the informations you gave and that still don"t responds to m problem, so i repost all and waiting for more help

Comment: Vector contains pointers - so it probably tries to sort pointers - Store the objects

Comment: as @ArtemyVysotsky said, you're sorting pointers;   if you don't want to store objects which can have an overhead, you could pass sort a comparason function

Comment: I feel that the question is incomplete. What is the definition of win()? And I see Schedule[1] two times..guess that one of them should be  Schedule[0]? Please elaborate more

Comment: @VidorVistrom I don't have any idea of how to insert a vector in a constructor.

Comment: Please i need some help

Answer (score 1):

Since `vector<Team*>` stores a pointer you need to overload the `operator<(const Team*, const Team*) operator` like so:

```
bool operator<(const Team* left, const Team* right) {
    return left->whatever < right->whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine. But only if `a_` is not `private`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  A(size_t const& a) : a_(a) {};
  ~A(){};

  //private:                                                                                                                                                    
  size_t a_;
};

bool operator<(A const& left, A const& right) {
  return left.a_ < right.a_;
}


int main() {
  std::vector<A*> v;
  v.push_back(new A(10));
  v.push_back(new A(6));
  v.push_back(new A(8));
  for(auto const& a : v) {
    std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
  }
  std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
  for(auto const& a : v) {
    std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Implement `operator<` as a member and that would be solved too:

```
bool operator<(A const& other) {
  return a_ < other.a_;
}
```

Then, `a_` can be private.

Comment: I have done `bool Team::isLower(Team const& B) const` cause `operator<` take two arguments and i have called it in `bool operator<(Team const&A, Team const& B)`  . you can take a look at the post below.